# Running system command from C++ application differs from commandline

Tags: c++, command-line

I want to execute a command from a C++ application. I do so using:

```
system("sendEmail.exe -f someone@somewhere.com -t ...");
```

This works on Windows Server 2008 and also on other systems. However, it does not work the same on my new server (Windows Server 2012), it seems to call the command but never completes. If I type the exact same command in a command window it works just fine.

I tried using

```
system("cmd.exe /C \"sendEmail.exe -f someone@somewhere.com -t ...\"");
```

but that did not help.

Anyone has an idea whats the difference between calling from C++ with system and running in a cmd?

**Edit:** The problem is not reproducible any more. Thanks for the fast answers

Comment: This seems more like a scripting job.

Comment: Maybe its executed in different user context.

Comment: Different environment (Path) ?

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, unfortunately the problem is now not reproducible any more. In the meantime I integrated the email client frome [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/98355/SMTP-Client-with-SSL-TLS) into my code.

Answer (score 3):

Try with

```
system("cmd.exe");
```

without parameters
This will just open a *cmd* window and leave it open. From that window you can call *sendMail.exe* and see what's happening. Perhaps there's just a different path setting or a permission issue.

As an alternative you can use the Windows Api function [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: This should help you - most likely windows UAC giving you problems.

Comment: What does CreateProcess() return? If false, what does GetLastError() return?
Did you try with system("cmd.exe") and calling your program manually from that window? What happened?

Comment: doing it in the window created by _system("cmd.exe")_ worked.

Comment: Now it also works directly. It is not reproducible any more. Thanky for all the comments.